# Switching from standalone Twig to Symfony Twig: Relative paths in templates

Tags: php, symfony, path, twig, relative-path

I used Twig without Symfony for some time now. Now I want to switch my whole application to symfony and use my old templates and i have problems with relative paths which I usually use with Twig:

I use something like this with standalone Twig:

```
function show_template() {
    global $lang;

    # $lang is "es" or "nl" etc
    $templates_dir = 'templates/'.$lang;

    # fallback dir if template is not found in the main location
    $fallback_dir = 'templates/en'

    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array($templates_dir, $fallback_dir));
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    #    'cache' => './cache',
    ));

    # $file is relative path to $templates_dir
    return $twig->render($file, $params);
}

show_template('index.html.twig');
```

and I also use relative paths in templates. i.e. io index.html.twig

```
{% include 'includes/header.html.twig' %}
hello world
{% include 'includes/footer.html.twig' %}
```

this is pretty simple but using this in Symfony2 is not possible in this form as I can see.

As I can see I have to use something like this:

```
$this->render('AcmeHelloBundle:Default:index.html.twig', $params);
```

And templates have to be changed to use following:

```
{% include '@AcmeHello/Default/includes/header.html.twig' %}
hello world
{% include '@AcmeHello/Default/includes/footer.html.twig' %}
```

I don't mind adapting my code/templats adding some new templating logic templates but I need to have flexible paths. Questions:

1. How can I use in PHP code relative paths to templates to be able to
   use changing templates_dir depending on language/whatever
2. How can I use relative path in templates?
3. How can I have a fallback templates/fallback directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by overriding the render() function in my controller.

```
public function render($template, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null) {   
    # default language/directory
    $lang = $this->container->getParameter('lang');
    $this->container->get('twig.loader')->addPath(__DIR__.'/../Resources/views/'.$lang);

    ## falback language/directory
    if ($lang != 'en') {
        $this->container->get('twig.loader')->addPath(__DIR__.'/../Resources/views/en');
    }

    return parent::render($template, $parameters, $response);
}  

public function myAction() {
    return $this->render('index.html.twig');
}
```

I then made a Resources/views subdirectories for every language, so now relative template paths and fallback templates work too:

```
{% include 'includes/header.html.twig' %}
hello world
{% include 'includes/footer.html.twig' %}
```

If includes/footer.html.twig is not availables in Resources/views/**es**/includes/ it will be taken from Resources/views/**en**/includes/